# set routerlink active on other pages

Tags: routerlinkactive

i want to make the sidebar option highlighted [routerlinkactive state] even when i navigate to other pages. So i have sidemenu component which is shown in home component

sidemenu compoennet html file

```
<div class="bg-primary sidebar">
<ul class="nav-sidebar"> 
    <li class="sidemenu-item" routerLinkActive="active">
        <a routerLink="/maincontent/first">
            <md-icon>first</md-icon><span>Sidemenu-item-1</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div>
```

home compoennet html file

```
<sidemenu></sidemenu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

routes file

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
        children: [
        { path: 'first', component : FirstComponent }
        { path: ':id' , component : SecondCompnent}
   ]
  }
 ];
```

By default Sidemenu-item-1 will be highlighted when I am in First component but i want that routerlink active state to be the same even when I navigate to Second Component replacing First Component. Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, have you find anything since then ?

Comment: No am still looking for an answer

Comment: I have found some not-so-satisfying but working trick... I add `a` elements in the `li`, which has the routes I want this li to be highlighted with, but no text and `class='hidden'`... So the `li` element is correctly highlighted.

Comment: i ll check on that @JeremyBelolo Thanks for your time to look into my problem